# Proxy .TXT list for cURL

Tags: php, list, curl, proxy

I need an always updated proxy list. I will parse it with PHP and use with cURL.
But i need only 3 countries (USA , UK, ITALY for example) proxies.

Where can i found a proxy list for this?

List can be text file , xml rss feed etc.

For example :

**USA.txt**

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8880
aaa.aaa.aaa.aa:8000
bbb.bbb.bb.bbb:8080
```

**ENGLAND.txt**

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8880
aaa.aaa.aaa.aa:8000
bbb.bbb.bb.bbb:8080
```

Comment: Why do you need proxies?

Comment: I want check webpages avaibility from a few points via curl + proxy.

Comment: You can set up a proxy on any VPS you rent. For less reliable free proxy lists, try [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+proxy+list).

Comment: I can't get any good and free proxy list which seperated by countries.

Comment: Then you didn't even look. These lists are always grouped by country. http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-283

Comment: @mario, i know this site. But i can't parse this webpage with PHP . Also, i can't get a list automatically with querystrings

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining a legitimate use case for this kind of thing.

Comment: If it's a web page, it's parseable. You just haven't looked at it hard enough (or at all) yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is almost exactly what you want:

**http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/txt-proxy-list.html**

Refreshed every hour.

Just like your needs, you can download txt [USA proxy list](http://proxy-ip-list.com/free-usa-proxy-ip.html) exclusively from that country if you want. Also updated hourly.

Comment: Last update: `Date: Thu Dec  6 23:59:02 PST 2012` looks a bit outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The always updated proxy list in `.TXT` format is available here:

http://www.proxy-list.org/en/vip-proxy-list.php

You can sort by country and type.

Comment: there is a captcha for free list :( And, for vip list , i have to login. How can i login automatically with php ?

Comment: You can login automatically by PHP using cURL with storing cookies. Moreover, since you're paying for VIP services, you may ask them to give you a direct link.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be free? If not, take a look at [this](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/premium/).