# PHP/MYSQL: Having a list of IPs how to detect if they are proxy servers?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proxy .TXT list for cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709234/proxy-txt-list-for-curl)

Do you know of any service/website that has a database of known proxy servers IPs, which I can use to compare remotely or locally various source IPs that I have in a database, in order to seperate the "real" ones?

Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that proxies are omnipresent and do not in themselves mean anything bad or put you in a situation where you would need to do anything special about them. Please be clear what kind of proxies you'd want to detect for what purpose.

Comment: Thanks, as I realized unfortunately there are no free solutions for this or no at all. Maxmind has a service that detects if an ip might be a proxy but other than that I haven't found anything more. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is currently no known master list of all proxies. New services pop up daily and its really not in anyones interest to keep track of them all.

However, if you want to check end users to see if they are possibly a proxy, look at `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`